# Compounded interest quarterly

Tags: arithmetic

Calculate the compound interest earned when 8000 is invested for 9 months at 5% per annum compounded quarterly.

I'm confuse with this question because compounded quarterly means that every 4 months interest will be earned?

4 + 4 = 8 months

There is an extra 1 month . What do I have to do with it ?

My workings

A = $ 8000 ( 1 + (5/3) / 100 )^2 
= 8002.22$

Another doubt I have is that do I divide the per annum rate by 3 if the question wants compounded quarterly ?

How do I do this question? Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Quarterly means $4$ times a year, that is, every $3$ months.

Comment: Also, your $5\%$ interest rate should be divided by $4$, not $3$.

Answer (score 1):

A quarter refers to a quarter of a year, or $3$ months.

So $9$ months is $3$ quarters.

And the quarterly rate is $\frac{5}{4} \%$.

The interest earned will therefore be $\$8000((1 + \frac{5}{400})^3 - 1) \approx  \$303.77$